# How to create a dedicated DLQ on TIBCO EMS?

Tags: tibco-ems

According to [this article](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-26904) in TIBCO JMS undelivered message are moved by default to `$sys.undelivered` (DLQ). The article states:

> Generally, a , sometimes referred to as an undelivered-message queue, is a holding queue for messages that cannot be delivered to their destination queues.
>
> In TIBCO EMS, if a message expires or has exceeded the value specified by the maxRedelivery property on a queue, the server checks the message's JMS_TIBCO_PRESERVE_UNDELIVERED property.
>
> If JMS_TIBCO_PRESERVE_UNDELIVERED is set to true, the server moves the message to the undelivered message queue, $sys.undelivered; If JMS_TIBCO_PRESERVE_UNDELIVERED is set to false, the server will delete the message.
>
> This undelivered message queue is a system queue that is always present and cannot be deleted.

Is it possible to put automatically undelivered message of a queue in a dedicated DLQ instead of the `$sys.undelivered` queue?

Comment: My company contacted TIBCO support. They provided a solution to put automatically undelivered message in a dedicated DLQ. This solution was given directly to administrators of queues in my enterprise. I don't know what was the agreed solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: The solution was inspired by this link: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.5.1/doc/html/GUID-0047893A-67E7-407C-BD21-C1FDFF020A79.html. A "selector" was used to filter the messages in the undelivered message queue and route them into a dedicated DLQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.5.1/doc/html/GUID-0047893A-67E7-407C-BD21-C1FDFF020A79.html) you should be able to create a selector to filter the messages sent to `$sys.undelivered` and route them to a different queue.